# Flutter not loading Image from Localhost

Tags: android, flutter

I have a little problem with the Network Image from Flutter.
When I try to load an Image from the internet it is working fine but as soon as I try to load from my Localhost it's showing nothing, no exception in the logcat, just nothing.
I have also looked to related questions but nothing from the mentioned solutions worked.
Here is an example URL http://IP_ADDRESS/path/to/image.jpg
I have already included the internet permission in Android manifest.
I am testing on a real Android device.

When I'm pasting the URL in my browser it shows the right image.

Comment: "I am testing on a real Android device" -- then there is no "Localhost", unless you are running a Web server on that device.

Comment: My device acts as a mobile hotspot and my PC is connected to it with xampp running. I have a standalone Android Version of the app I am trying to port to flutter  and there everything is working as expected, so I don't think that the problem lies there but I thank you for the quick response.

Comment: If you find a way to do so can you please share it with me. I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

i set the base url on flutter app as my local computer ip first
then when i get url image from server i change the "localhost" part into computer ip address and it showen in the app and external device also

Answer (score -1):

the url link for image must be seen by your device , in your case localhost means your phone device but not your computer . if your device is a PC and you are using web browser then you will not see the localhost (in adroid device) , if your device is android phone (usb or virtual) then you have to use your computer ip instead of using localhost like :
http://192.168.1.10/myproject/images/myimage.png
because the localhost in this case is the webserver installed on your device .

if you want to use localhost like :
http://localhost/myproject/images/myimage.png
then you have to install a webserver on your mobile device.